# PyQt Installation warning "Nmake, warning U4006"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am a new pythoner and trying to install pyqt4 on python 2.7.13 64bit, win7 OS bit(plus vs2013). To do this, I download pyqt4 and sip, qt5.9.1(latest versions)

SIP and qt5.9.1 were installed without a problem, while when I installed pyqt4, i got a warning about nmake.

"python configure.py" was ran properly.
The problem was coming out when I ran name against pyqt folder.
I was trying to find a answer from other where. Most of those tell me to remove "spaces" in the path, while I can confirm there is no spaces in any path related to the installation.

Any help is appreciated.

See capture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I manually modified the makefile under the problematic location, then run nmake, this fixed the problem.

That was to add "translator.h" head file following the moc command

While I still not understand why "python configure.py" did not give me a runnable makefile.

```
    $(MOC) -o moc_translator.cpp translator.h $<
```

it will be apaprecaited if someone can clarify this situation.

Makefile

[image]

Translator.h

[image]